# iReport Designer Characters replaced by question marks?

Tags: jasper-reports

Using arabic characters in iReport Designer, the content characters of the generated PDF file are replaced by question marks

**THE REQUIRED FONTS ARE INSTALLED**

How to solve this???

Comment: What makes you think you installed the required fonts? If you have not added a font extension, the result is that the characters are not rendered (and this is your result, so it seems possible the font extension is not installed). Identity-H is a good choice for Arabic. Update the question with the version of iReport.

Comment: What makes you think you installed the required fonts? What updated behavior do you see?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same question marks appeared

Comment: Seriously, what makes you think you installed the required fonts? Update your question to include, "Before I installed them I observed A, B, and C. Here are the steps I used to install them. After I installed them I see this change, so I know they are installed." I promise to stop asking the question if you answer it.

Comment: @mdahlman I installed the required fonts

Comment: It's possible (likely!) that you're right. But it's not at all clear what you're claiming. The fonts are installed on the machine? Recognized by the OS? Installed in the JVM? Created as Font Extensions? the font extensions are in the classpath of your Java app? Something slightly different?
It's really important to explain in much greated detail what you have in mind when you say FONTS ARE INSTALLED, though the all caps aren't necessarily needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Jasper Environment "IReport"
   If you want to generate *a PDF report* for example
   Its better to choose **(Preview -> PDF Preview)** from your ireport app
   NOT default value (Internal Preview)
2. Text fields properties

For Text fields you should to assign some properties
 1. **Font name** : a font that support your locale "Arabic"
 2. **Pdf font name** : a font that support your locale "Arabic"
 3. **Pdf Embeded** : true
 4. **Pdf Encoding** : depend on your language "Arabic" -> "Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)"

Note
If you does NOT install a font that support your language "Arabic"
Its so easy
Just get your favorite font "....ttf"
Then install it from ireport
**(Tools -> Options -> Fonts tab -> Install Font button -> .... )**

Comment: Yes: setting the Font name is important. No: setting the Pdf font name, embedding, and encoding should not be done. This was deprecated years ago. The Pdf font is specified by the "Font name". YES: defining the Font Extension is almost certainly the step that is needed to solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried all above suggested but no use and still the question marks appears

Comment: What is exactly your problem @user2079954 ??

Comment: Characters are replaced by question marks in the PDF generated by iReports

Answer (score 1):

From version 4.8.0 of the IReport,  Just change the font of textfield  from sanserif to Dejavu sans.

Answer (score -2):

try to enlarge the report text field size. Hope it will be resolved.
Please mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but the result is the same and there were no changes